# How to return UIElement or XAML as content in WPF Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Hi and excuse me for my bad english.

Well... I'm trying to bind to a list of objects to fill my ItemsControl. Object represents a pair of name and value of settings taken from config file. The purpose is to make some settings editor which saves edited data back to file.

Object is quite simple:

```
MySettings
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

There is some simple markup (this is a sketch, not exact project):

```
<ItemsControl Name="myItmCtrl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <!--Name of the property-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <!--Its value-->
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And at the end i'm adding `myItmCtrl.ItemsSource = List<MySettings>;` in code-behind.

It all works fine as it shoud.

Then I desided to advance my form because some of the `Value`s (which are all stored as strings) can take values of `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` which can be easily converted to `bool`. So, instead of typing TRUE or FALSE in some cases, I want to represent those values by kinda different UIElement - `CheckBox` - and then bind to its `IsChecked` property.

So, I want that string values were represented by `TextBox`es and bool values by `CheckBox`es. I'd could do it in code-behind and create elements on the fly in loop through `List<MySettings>` but i didn't. The idea is to find some tricky extension which can describe all of it (or some 50/50 xaml/code-behind) in XAML.

Many thanks

Comment: Read about [DataTemplateSelector](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be using a `ValueConverter` that converts between string and bool values. Since we already got some decent methods for how to convert strings to booleans and vice versa, this shouldn't be a problem. You can build your own `ValueConverter` just as the article mentioned by amnezjak describes.

The binding for your `TextBox` may be as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
```

`myConverter` being the key to the actual converter you've imported.